# How to edit the `$PATH` variable

Tags: environment-variables

Where exactly is the `$PATH` variable stored? I am changing the `/etc/environment` file with my desired path. Then I am doing `echo $PATH` and the old version is showed.

Answer (score 5):

Rebooting will work or you can run at a terminal

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: No, `source /etc/environment` will apply the change only to the current shell's environment, try opening a terminal, changing `/etc/environment`, sourcing it, closing the terminal and reopening another terminal. Rebooting is required when changing `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Yeah, @Terrance is right, also just logging out / logging in will do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing the `/etc/environment` file, all you have to do is log out of your account and log back in for the changes to take effect.  It is best for your account to follow through the other link that has been posted in the comments of the original question.